# How to properly cancel pending alarms

Tags: android

I can't seem to find an answer to this, but what is the criteria for passing in a matching `PendingIntent` to be removed from an alarm? It it based on the just the name like com.blah.package.myclass or do the `Extra`s matter?

For example, I'm doing something like this and all alarms fire the same intent:

```
    public void setAlarm(Context context, long nextAlarmMillis) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("alarm", this);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234 /* unused */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get the AlarmManager service
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(sender);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextAlarmMillis, sender);
    }
```

What happens is that the `Alarm` class can be altered, etc and passed in as an `Extra`. I am canceling the previous alarm, but I'm not sure if it's doing anything or if any left over alarms will remain.

Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is mentioned in `AlarmManager` documentation

> Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)), will be canceled.

Which, the [filterEquals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29) is defined as:

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

I think the easiest to do is you keep the reference of `PendingIntent` passed to AlarmManager, and pass it to cancel. Or have a factory method to construct such pi.

Comment: Ahh, missed the filterEquals(). Thank you.